# cvExtractSURF throwing exception, incorrect size of input array ( ) in cvCreateSeq

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, opencv

I'm using the following code with OpenCV on a Mac. The following function receives a path to an image file from another function, and that works fine. However, cvExtractSURF throws an exception stating:

> OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array () in cvCreateSeq, file >/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarb>alls_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.1/modules/core/src/datastructs.cpp, line 372
>   terminate called throwing an exception

The code is as follows:

```
- (int)extractFromImagePath:(NSString*)pathToFile{
[self.statusText setStringValue:@"image received"];
NSLog(@"Path: %@",pathToFile);
// Path: /Users/loco/Desktop/testimage.png

const char * path = [pathToFile UTF8String];
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
cv::Mat im = cv::imread(path,0);
if(im.data == NULL) 
{
    std::cout<<"Unable to read "<<path<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}    

/* extract the SURF keypoints/descriptors of an image */
// presumes a previously declared IplImage *image
CvSeq *keypoints = NULL;
CvSeq *descriptors = NULL;
CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvExtractSURF(image, NULL, &keypoints, &descriptors, storage, cvSURFParams(0, 600));
// OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array () in cvCreateSeq, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.1/modules/core/src/datastructs.cpp, line 372
// terminate called throwing an exception


[self.statusText setStringValue:@"writing to files"];

/* build a path to save a file in the documents directoy */
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *xmlpath_kp = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"keypoints.xml"];
NSString *xmlpath_desc = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"descriptors.xml"];

/* serialize to xml and save to disc */
cvSave([xmlpath_kp UTF8String], keypoints);
cvSave([xmlpath_desc UTF8String], descriptors);

[self.statusText setStringValue:@"done"];
/* don't forget your cleanup ;) */
cvReleaseImage(&image);
cvClearMemStorage(storage);
return 1;
}
```

Would anybody know what's going on? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could running the app in 64 bit mode be the issue? As else I'll have to recompile OpenCV.

Comment: It was a bug in 2.4.0 & 2.4.1. Should be fixed in just released OpenCV 2.4.2.

Comment: Good job, you guys did fix it in 2.4.2! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrey Kamaev pointed out, it was a bug in 2.4.0 & 2.4.1. Upgrading did fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested part of your code that throwing error.The following code is not giving any error, just check it out.

```
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("C:\\Koala.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
CvSeq* kp_pns;
CvSeq* desct;
CvSURFParams pams;
pams.hessianThreshold=10;
pams.nOctaveLayers=4;
pams.nOctaves=3;
pams.upright = true;
CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvExtractSURF(image,NULL,&kp_pns,&desct,storage,pams,0);
```

I am able to extract the surf keypoints without any error. I hope the error will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I just tried it out, unfortunately it throws back the same error...

I've got a feeling it's got something to do with me running it in 64bit mode, see line 89: http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/8811/entry/trunk/opencv/modules/legacy/src/features2d.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Adjust hessianThreshold for SURF;
from OpenCV they say;

> **hessianThreshold** only features with hessian larger than that are
>   extracted. good default value is ~300-500 (can depend on the average
>   local contrast and sharpness of the image). user can further filter
>   out some features based on their hessian values and other
>   characteristics.